# CoreNLP Failure to Load Language Specific Properties

Tags: stanford-nlp, corenlp-server

I'm trying to get Stanford CoreNLP to run properly as a server (though problem probably affects non-server uses), but keep getting this error:

`"ERROR CoreNLP - Failure to load language specific properties"`.

It still works, but it may not have everything it needs to work well.

I started with the base download.  When I saw the above error, I downloaded and placed, in the CoreNLP directory, the english models jar and english-kbp models jar.  These two are huge and don't seem to correspond to anything in the base download.  But, still, I get the above error after restarting the server.  I also tried adding

> -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-english.properties

to the command line, but this gives an error saying it couldn't read the properties file.

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Sure, it's the server activation line straight off the Stanford website:  java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000

Comment: I could be wrong, but perhaps the error message is just a minor bug in the CoreNLP software. The code that throws the error has a comment that "// check to see if a specific language was set, use language specific properties".  Nothing on the download page or server start page suggests it's necessary to set English.  Unfortunately, I'm not set up to trace the error to its source very easily.

Comment: Then again, when I did an OpenIE annotation of the same sentence used on the page http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html , I get a very different (and erroneous) result than what is presented on that page.  So maybe I don't have everything I need.

Comment: @JasonK where you able to solve it?

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I add StanfordCoreNLP.properties under the unzipped stanford-corenlp-full directory.

Comment: I think "works" isn't really the correct term here. It merely hides the error, nothing more. Nonetheless it's a useful hint if you just want to get rid of the error.